# имя нажатого пункта listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Нужно получить имя после длительного нажатия на пукт ListView.
Сразу замечу: пункт кастомный. Нужно получать имя из tvItemName.

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_list">

</ImageView>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#545b54"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvItemDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textColor="#545b54"
    android:textSize="16sp">

</TextView>
```

Comment: Код адаптера в студию

Answer (score 2):

Если исходить именно из таких условий, то вешайте `Listener` на `ListView` следующим образом:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName)).getText().toString();
        Log.e("Log", "Name is " + name);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо) И без всяких "код в студию" и т.д и т.п.

Comment: Если помогло, отметьте ответ решением :)

Comment: Как это сделать?)

Comment: @Evgeny Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.